# What are Subscriptions in RxJS and how do Observables interact with them?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I don't have it very clear on how Observables and Subscriptions work. In particular how an Observable and its Subscriptions exchange information.

So to make explicit questions:

- Does an Observable keep references to its Subscriptions?
- Does a Subscription keep a reference to the Observable that created it?
- Does an Observable "put" data in its Subscriptions or does a Subscription "poll" its Observable?
- How does the information exchange happen?

Comment: take your title place it on google - first result: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tux1nhBPl_w

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://angular.io/guide/observables) from the Angular documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Subscription` is the result of an `Observer` getting added to an `Observable`. It is an object that can only be used to `unsubscribe` from that Observable. When unsubscribed, the Observer won't receive any further emissions.

The `Observer` (which you might be referring to as Subscription) is what gets created when you call `Observable.subscribe(next, error, complete)`. You'll receive the `Observer` when implementing your own Observable with `Observable.create()`. Otherwise, you won't get a hold of it. The Observer holds the `next(value => void)`, `error(error => void)` and `complete(_ => void)` functions that are used by the Observable to communicate state changes.

Exchanging information only happens in one direction. The Observable always emits to the Observer, never the other way round.

Now for your questions:

> Does an Observable keep references to its Subscriptions?

No, it keeps references to its `Observers`, but that's probably what you mean.

> Does a Subscription keep a reference to the Observable that created it?

No, only a function that is used for unsubscribing from that Observable. An `Observer` also doesn't have a reference to the Observable that it's subscribed to.

> Does an Observable "put" data in its Subscriptions or does a Subscription "poll" its Observable?

The Observable "puts" (better word would be "emits") values to its `Observers`. There is *never* any polling from an Observable, as this would violate the fundamental principal of RxJS. One exception would be `BehaviourSubject.getValue()`, but you shouldn't use that in most cases!

> How does the information exchange happen?

It depends on the Observable. Generally, an `Observable` holds a list of all its `Observers` and calls their `next()` functions whenever a new value is emitted, the `error()` function when an error occurs and the `complete()` function when it reached its completeness state.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your question is related to a more general observer pattern, here is a good article about this in
JS [example](https://pawelgrzybek.com/the-observer-pattern-in-javascript-explained/) or more general use [example](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer) you will get all your answers.